# PIL remove different pixels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm working on an image treatment program, where it (kind of) creates a popart image. The thing is, i get some "intruder" pixels, where a blue zone has some green pixels here and there. I want to make those pixels disappear, but I can't seem to find a way to do so. If you have also another way to make a popart image, feel free to propose. Here's my script:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image

def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def PopArt():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            if o<85:
                px1[x,y]=(0,0,255)
            elif 85<o<170:
                px1[x,y]=(0,255,0)
            elif o>170:
                px1[x,y]=(255,0,0)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)






main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
currdir = os.getcwd()
a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
main.deiconify()

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")

Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
nuxy=nux.load()
for x in range(z[0]):
    for y in range(z[1]):
        nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
nux.save("Blank.png")








if z>(400,400):
    im2 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="ImageBlank.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED, length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)
elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    imt = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)

s=S1.get()




main.mainloop()
```

Just to help, here is the part of the program that makes the popart image:

```
def PopArt():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            if o<85:
                px1[x,y]=(0,0,255)
            elif 85<o<170:
                px1[x,y]=(0,255,0)
            elif o>170:
                px1[x,y]=(255,0,0)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
```

And here are the images and their results:

[image: face.png]
[image: chev.png]

[image: face.png modified]
[image: chev.png modified]

If anything is needed just ask I'm always available

EDIT: Here is the snap of code I was talking about in the comments, you just snap it in the end of the Popart function:

```
n=0
j=0
q=0

for x in range(1,z[0]):      
    for y in range(1,z[1]):
        for t in range(-1,1):    #These two loops change the pixel "coordinates"
            for w in range(-1,1):
                v=px1[x+t,y+w]
                if v[0]==255:
                    n=n+1
                elif v[1]==255:  #These are the counters
                    j=j+1
                elif v[2]==255:
                    q=q+1

        Max=n        #And this checks the dominant color
        if j>Max:
            Max=j
        elif q>Max:
            Max=q
        elif j>q:
            Max=j

        if n==Max:
            px2[x,y]=(255,0,0)   #And here I assign the color depending on the surrounding colors
        elif j==Max:
            px2[x,y]=(0,255,0)
        elif q==Max:
            px2[x,y]=(0,0,255)
        n=0
        j=0
        q=0
Ima3.save("ImageMod.png")
```

And this is what I get:

[image: face.png modified]

I know I made a mistake when I started using simple name variables `z`, I should've used things like `Original_Image`. The program has too many variables to change them all now, but in my future projects I won't be doing this mistake.

Comment: Can you add a brief outline of how your algorithm works? `EchelleDeGris` suggests *grayscale*, right?

Comment: @RadLexus Yeah I wrote it in french `EchelleDeGris()` indeed means _grayscale_, `SupprimerImage()` removes the image, `Luminosite()` changes the brightness of the image depending on the scale value, `AnnulerModifications()` kind of cancels the effects added to the image, and `PopArt()` is obvious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I think you have unhelpful naming in your program. It is not only 
about french function names, it is mostly about short variable names like "z".

But if I'm correct, I see you know how to read and write RGB code for each pixel in a two-dimensional matrix. So you just need to analyze eight neighbors for your each pixel - if a pixel has more than half of differently colored neighbors - color it accordingly to the most popular neighbor color. Repeat until all pixels have the same colored most popular neighbors.

Of course, this is just a simple logic, and may be improved, but I hope, I'd shown the idea.

Upd:

I wrote some code implementing my idea. Works very slow, but result seems correct.

```
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter


def get_pixel(pixels, x, y):
    try:
        return pixels[x, y]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def get_neighbors(pixels, x, ):
    neighbors = list()
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y + 1))
    return neighbors


def filter_art(pixels, size):
    indexes = dict()
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            color = get_pixel(pixels, x, y)
            neighbors = get_neighbors(pixels, x, y)
            new_color = Counter(neighbors).most_common()[0][0]
            if new_color is not None:
                indexes[x, y] = new_color
    for x, y in indexes:
        pixels[x, y] = indexes[x, y]


def pop_art(path_orig, path_mod, coef):  # coef is integer value, meant how deep filtering would be (for example, coef=4)
    image_orig = Image.open(path_orig)
    size = image_orig.size
    image_mod = Image.new("RGB",(size[0],size[1]))
    pixels_orig = image_orig.load()
    pixels_mod = image_mod.load()
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            p = pixels_orig[x, y]
            if isinstance(p, int): # this should be done using PIL palletes and converting to exact pallete at first,
                # but now I omit this for my quick test
                rgb = (p,p,p)
            elif isinstance(p, tuple) and len(p) in (3, 4):
                rgb = p[:3]
            else:
                raise TypeError('Unknown pallete')
            average_color = sum(rgb) / 3
            if average_color <= 85:
                pixels_mod[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)  # you also need care about guarantee correct PIL pallete format here (omitted)
            elif 85 < average_color <= 170:
                pixels_mod[x, y] = (0, 255, 0)
            elif pixels_mod[x, y] > 170:
                pixels_mod[x, y] = (0, 0, 255)
    for _ in range(coef):
        filter_art(pixels_mod, size)
    image_mod.save(path_mod)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pop_art('obama.png', 'result.png', coef=4)
```

[image]

Comment: I've already tried this and it gives me awful results. I expect it to remove the 'intruder' pixels, but it ust makes them even bigger. I made a counter for eight pixels around it (square of 3x3) and it counts the colors (I have absolute values like (0,0,255). Then I check the dominant color and assign it to the original one but it doesn't. I added the snap of code I am talking about in my post.

Comment: I wrote the code that implementing my idea. But I was made to include deepness coefficient to implement correct graphic in reasonable time in addition. You probably have a mistake somewhere in your try. Though, my code has too bad performance anyway and needs to be improved significantly. I added the code and resulting picture to my answer.

Comment: Another idea is make algorithm which finds solid zones with less area than some coefficient. For sure it should be made in one iteration by pixels grid. Your task to implement fast good algorithm is not so trivial, so you would need to think hard, or find existed one for same task (some like that should be definitely already exist, but i think the idea is learn how to).